# How would you unwrap 'football' like shape to have a world map as a texture?

Tags: uv

Pretty straight forward question, I am not sure about the answer though. I have attached the screenshot of a 'football'like shape that i'd like to unwrap and use world map as a texture on it. Any ideas?

[image]

Thank you for your help,
Waqas

[Download Blend File](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=11514179225556378623)

Comment: Keep in front ortho and select the center edges and sub divide once and select that center edge and make mark seam. Then unrwap the 2 halfs

Comment: Thank you, I am close to what I want because the UV's are not well aligned. I will work on it but a big help. Thank you once again :)

Comment: can you attach the image you are going to wrap on that sphere

Comment: Any image is fine atek...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "World Map", you mean an equirectangular image, you don't have to unwrap it at all. Just use an *Environment Texture* node instead of an *Image Texture* node and plug the *Object* coordinates into the *Vector* input. Node setup and result:

[image]

And `.blend` file:

[image]

Comment: I used the Environment Texture as you said, it still maps the texture separately on each of the faces. Also the attached image is missing, I can't see the solution.

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/6d80a943c7.png - This is what's happening to my object.

Comment: @iowaqas Imgur should be back up now so you can see the result. What happened to yours doesn't make sense. Is your model one contiguous object?

Comment: @iowaqas I just downloaded your .blend file and I still can't replicate your result with your mesh.

Comment: I really have no idea. Yes, it's one single object. Can I please have a look at the blend file that you made?

Comment: @iowaqas There you go.

Comment: @iowaqas The reason is that your ball is UV unwrapped and the UVs are overlapping. Make sure you include the _Texture Coordinate_ node and use _Object_ coordinates, as in Scott's image above, and it should work.